Cross validation on XGBoost using callback of optuna
I am trying yo use optuna and cross_validate from sklearn also using the callback function from optuna. My code is below.
It seems that the callback does not work here and I do not know why ... I don't see the intermediate value when printing it.
The code works but it semms that the code does not call the callback function of Optuna, hence it does not prune any trial. Do you know why?
def optuna_objective_xgb(trial):
    # define hy
    params = {
        'n_estimators' : trial.suggest_categorical('n_estimators', [20, 50, 100, 200]), # Number of boosting rounds i.e. number of trees
        'max_depth': trial.suggest_categorical('max_depth', [14, 18, 22, 26, 30, 34, 38, 42, 46, 50]), # max depth of the trees
        'learning_rate': trial.suggest_categorical('learning_rate', [0.01, 0.1, 0.3]), # learning rateof the boosting 
        'gamma': trial.suggest_categorical('gamma',[0, 0.25, 0.5, 1]), # pruning parameter (Minimum loss reduction required to make a further partition on a leaf node of the tree)
        'reg_lambda' : trial.suggest_float('reg_lambda', 0, 1, step = 0.1), # penalty : used when the similarity score is computed
        'subsample': trial.suggest_float('subsample',0.1,1, step = 0.1), # for each tree, we are using a random subset of the data (% of rows)
        'colsample_bytree': trial.suggest_float('colsample_bytree',0.1,1, step = 0.1), # for each tree, we sample using a sample of the columns (% of columns used)
        'min_child_weight' : 0,  # also named cover --> minimum number of residuals in a leaf
        'eval_metric': 'pre', # metric to monitor for early stopping
    }

    
    pruning_callback = optuna.integration.XGBoostPruningCallback(trial,  "test-pre")
    
    xgb_model = xgb.XGBClassifier(**params, random_state=10, n_jobs = -1, callback = [pruning_callback]) # XGBRegressor if regression
    
    scores = cross_validate(xgb_model, X_train, y_train, verbose=1,
                n_jobs=-1, scoring="precision", cv=4,)
    
    return scores["test_score"].mean()

The warning that appears is the following :

Thank for your support.

I think callbacks=[pruning_callback] should be used instead of callback=pruning_callback.

Thanks a lot for your support !
I think what you told works, but now I have another issue telling me:
All the 4 fits failed.
It is very likely that your model is misconfigured.
You can try to debug the error by setting error_score='raise'.
KeyError: 'test-pre'

Do you have any idea why ? And how to overcome this issue ?

Could you share the minimal reproducible code?

It is the same code but you just need to replace callbacks=[pruning_callback] instead of callback=[pruning_callback]. Then, you can use whatever X_train et y_train that you want, you should see the same error when running the objective function.
You need to run study = optuna.create_study(direction="maximize", sampler = optuna.samplers.TPESampler(seed = 20))  study.optimize(lambda trial: objective(trial, X_train, y_train), n_trials=50) in order to search for the best hyperparemeters.
Thanks for your help
